# can’t build the app for android after ejecting to native project

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, expo

After ejecting my expo project to native one

I can’t export APK file

what I wonder is , why considering this task : ??

> Task :app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets FAILED

I ejected expo , it fails always in this task

here’s the full logs from Android Studio

```
Opening `/dev/tty` failed (6): Device not configured
resize:  can't open terminal /dev/tty
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                         │
│   There is a new version of expo-cli available (3.20.0).                │
│   You are currently using expo-cli 3.13.8                               │
│   Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice;   │
│   for example: `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version      │
│                                                                         │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
[03:17:25] Cannot read property 'publishManifestPath' of undefined
[03:17:25] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseExpoUpdatesAssets'.
> Process 'command './node_modules/expo-updates/run-expo.sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```